# Python extract italic content from html

Tags: python, html, italic

I am trying to extract 'Italic' Content from a pdf in python. I have converted the pdf to html so that I can use the italic tag to extract the text. 
Here is how the html looks like

```
<br></span></div><div style="position:absolute; border: textbox 1px
solid; writing-mode:lr-tb; left:71px; top:225px; width:422px;
height:15px;"><span style="font-family: TTPGFA+Symbol; font-
size:12px">•</span><span style="font-family: YUWTQX+ArialMT; font-
size:14px">  Kornai, Janos. 1992. </span><span style="font-family:
PUCJZV+Arial-ItalicMT; font-size:14px">The Socialist System: The
Political Economy of Communism</span><span style="font-family:
YUWTQX+ArialMT; font-size:14px">.
```

This is how the code looks:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(open("/../..myfile.html"))
bTags = []
for i in soup.findAll('span'):
    bTags.append(i.text)
```

I am not sure how can I get only the italic text.

Comment: Is the text italic via <em>, <i>, inline styles, or CSS?

Comment: I don't know `BeautifulSoup`, but you probably need to get the `style` attribute of the tag and check if it contains `Italic`. Print `i` to see if it has a `attributes` key, for example.

Comment: @Julien from the sample it looks like you need to check the `style` attribute to see if `font-family` contains `Italic`.

Comment: .@Camil, my point was that there are many ways that text can be italic on an HTML page. Checking the `style` attribute would only cover if it is set via inline styles, and none of the other ways. Also, since this HTML is being auto-generated, it's safe to assume that it will be consistent, so it doesn't make sense to cover all the different possibilities. EDIT: Sorry, for some reason I did not see the example HTML...

Comment: I could only find converting into html as the only solution to extract italic text from a pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
bTags = []
for i in soup.find_all('span', style=lambda x: x and 'Italic' in x):
    bTags.append(i.text)

print bTags
```

Passing a function to the `style` argument will filter results by the result of that function, with its input as the value of the `style` attribute. We check to see if the string `Italic` is inside the attribute, and if so, return True.

You may need a more sophisticated algorithm depending on the rest of what your HTML looks like.